# text editor - make bold button sunken

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a bold button for a text editor. I'm having trouble with setting the button "sunken" when bold text is selected.

I imagine it will be something like the below?

```
self.textPad.tag_bind("bt","<Button-1>",self.boldP())

def boldP(self):
        self.boldB.config(relief="sunken")
```

Not sure if I got the right idea, could someone please shed some light on this for me?

Comment: yes I'm working on tkinter

Comment: What type is `self.textPad`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the main problem, but one problem with the code snippet that you posted is that you are not actually giving a callback to `tag_bind`, you are giving it `None`. Why? Because you are calling `boldP`, which returns `None`. Change this line:

```
self.textPad.tag_bind("bt","<Button-1>",self.boldP())
```

To:

```
self.textPad.tag_bind("bt", "<Button-1>", self.boldP)
```

Another problem is that your callback should take an event argument:

```
def boldP(self, event):
    ...
```

I'm not too familiar with Tkinter, so I'm not so sure about how `tag_bind` is supposed to work - but it seems like it's mostly used with `canvas` objects. Is this what you are doing? Otherwise try `bind`. Something like this:

```
self.button.bind(,"<Button-1>", self.boldP)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working for me, I'm not too sure about the second bit there with setting def boldP(self, event): 
just wondering why we need to have 'event' in the parameter?

Comment: Please see: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

The event object is passed so that you can get more information about what happened, such as the mouse x and y coordinates and which widget triggered the event.

Comment: That's what SO is for :) The best way to show gratitude is to accept correct answers and to upvote helpful/good ones.

Comment: cool thanks, I thought upvote the answer would accept it as the correct one :) cheers